# Vue - how to pass additional param to callback method

Tags: vue.js, callback, vuejs2

I have a Vue component that has an $emit event.  I'd like to have a method that receives the callback (with data from the $emit), but also accepts another parameter.  I would think that having a method return a function would accomplish this, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
<my-component @callback="notifyCallback" />
```

I can easily receive the data from the $emit like this:

```
methods: {
  notifyCallback(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

But I would like to use the same callback method for multiple $emit events with different names, while still receiving the data sent from the $emit.  My thinking is that having the method return a function would do the trick.  Something like this:

```
<my-component 
  @callback-a="notifyCallback('callback-a')"
  @callback-b="notifyCallback('callback-b')"
/>

methods: {
  notifyCallback(callbackKey) {
    return function(data) {
      console.log(`Callback: ${callbackKey} has data: ${data}`)
    }
  }
}
```

But this approach of having the method return a function doesn't seem to work.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly? Is there a way to accomplish having a method return a function?

Or, more directly at my desired goal ... is there a way to have a callback method receive an extra parameter along with the data in the $emit?

Thanks so much for your input!

*Note: I realize I could pass the callbackKey with the $emit data, but the approach of having a method return a function seems like it should work, so I'm mostly curious about why it isn't, and what I'm misunderstanding.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v-on` directive takes either a method name or an [inline handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers). The inline handler's return value is unused, and returning a function would not setup a new event handler. Your inline handler generates a function with `notifyCallback()` and does nothing with it.

Note that the inline handler has a special variable (`$event`) that contains the event data from `$emit()`.

A small tweak to your original code could accomplish your goal, but it seems suboptimal for your use case, as it unnecessarily creates the same callback on every event:

```
<my-component 
  @callback-a="notifyCallback('callback-a')($event)"
  @callback-b="notifyCallback('callback-b')($event)"
/>
```

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<div>
      <button @click="emitData('callback-a')">Event A</button>
      <button @click="emitData('callback-b')">Event B</button>
    </div>`,
  methods: {
    emitData(eventName) {
      this.$emit(eventName, {
        foo: `${eventName} 1`,
        bar: `${eventName} 2`,
      })
    }
  }  
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    notifyCallback(callbackKey) {
      return function(data) {
        console.log(`Callback: ${callbackKey} has data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component 
    @callback-a="notifyCallback('callback-a')($event)"
    @callback-b="notifyCallback('callback-b')($event)"
  />
</div>
```

A cleaner solution might be to handle the event directly in `notifyCallback()`:

```
<my-component 
  @callback-a="notifyCallback('callback-a', $event)"
  @callback-b="notifyCallback('callback-b', $event)"
/>

methods: {
  notifyCallback(callbackKey, data) {
    console.log(`Callback: ${callbackKey} has data: ${data}`)
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<div>
      <button @click="emitData('callback-a')">Event A</button>
      <button @click="emitData('callback-b')">Event B</button>
    </div>`,
  methods: {
    emitData(eventName) {
      this.$emit(eventName, {
        foo: `${eventName} 1`,
        bar: `${eventName} 2`,
      })
    }
  }  
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    notifyCallback(callbackKey, data) {
      console.log(`Callback: ${callbackKey} has data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component 
    @callback-a="notifyCallback('callback-a', $event)"
    @callback-b="notifyCallback('callback-b', $event)"
  />
</div>
```